# How to add a dataframe to another dataframe created via generator in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[9, 9, 8]})
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([i], columns=['A']) for i in range(5)], ignore_index=True)
```

I would like to add those 2 dataframes together in 1 line via pd.concat

I have tried this:

```
df2 = pd.concat([(pd.DataFrame({'A':[9, 9, 8]})), (pd.DataFrame([i], columns=['A']) for i in range(5))], ignore_index=True)
```

I am getting the following error message:
"TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'generator'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

How is it done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code

```
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'A':[9, 9, 8]})]+ [pd.DataFrame([i], columns=['A']) for i in range(5)] , ignore_index=True)

df2
Out[17]: 
   A
0  9
1  9
2  8
3  0
4  1
5  2
6  3
7  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to append and ignore index

```
df2.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

    A
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   9
6   9
7   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```

result:

```
   A
0  9
1  9
2  8
3  0
4  1
5  2
6  3
7  4
```